# How to check in Django template if user has delete permission?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I would like to check if the user has permission to delete an object in the template.
If the user has permission, I display or enable the button.
Permissions are per group.
How can I implement this in the Django template?

```
{% if ... %} 
    <button><a href="/delete">Delete</a></button>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions of the user are stored in the `perms` variable, as [specified in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions). You thus can check if a user has a delete permission for a model with:

```
{% if perms.app_name.delete_model_name %}
    …
{% endif %}
```

with *`app_name`* and *`modelname`* the name of the app and the model respectively.

---

> **Note**: It is advisable to make use of the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) where the URL is resolved based on the *name* of a view instead of hardcoding URLs in the template.